# CSS Constant Height Dynamic Width With Truncating

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have an image and I want the height to be constant.
The width I want to be 100% of the container.
However, as you shrink the container, I want the image to truncate the right hand side so it doesn't go out of proportion.

Comment: Got some code that you've tried?

Comment: It sounds like you just want an image with a set width and height; the natural behavior for an image with a set width is to truncate it when the container is made too small, and you said you want the height to be constant. If you DON'T want a set width and height, in what case would you like the image to change its size?

Answer (score 1):

You want the **height** to be 100% and the **visible** width to be 100%.  Something like this:

```
<div id="container"><img src="http://mypic.jpeg" /></div>

div#container { height: 200px; width: 150px; overflow: hidden; }
div#container img { height: 100%;}
```